# Repeat textbox on each page in a report

Tags: reporting-services

i have a report which contains a vertical text on the right side of the page. This text appears in the first page. But my customer wants that text appears in every single page of the report. How can i make that text appears in every single page of the report? I can't move that text to the header neither to the footer. I put a photo which can describe my wish. I want that '2.10-F38 Rev.6' appears in every page. It is in the body. Could anyone help me?

[image]

Comment: use list control to repeat this content in every page.

Comment: i tried it but couldn't make it work.  do you know how to work it?

Comment: I share the file on below link go through it.   http://ssrsmegabits.blogspot.in/2014/09/ssrs-list-demo-using-ssrs.html

Comment: thank you @Manoj it works but this is not what im looking for. I have some textboxes one under the other on the report. I dont have a table. The reports comes out in one page but sometimes in 2-3 pages depend on the textboxes' content. Theoretically we can't know in how many pages the report will come out or we dont have a dataset so that we cant use table control. Imagine that there is a textbox in the photo above, and the content is very large so that the report will come out in two pages. is there a way to repeat that '2.10-F38 Rev.6' text on the second page?

Answer (score 0):

The only way I got around this issue was to create an image with the vertical text and add it as a "BackgroundImage" to the "Body" element...
[image]

It's a horrible solution at a technical level but if you think about it many companies buy their A4/Letter paper from printing services with the company header logo and details already printed...  So it doesn't make me feel so bad.

Comment: Text in images used in this way can appear blurred at times, so do be careful about resizing the image and the quality of the original image.